# VueJS test-utils can't find element inside child component

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to use `findComponent` with `find` method to find a child component's element and set it's value. But every time I run test, it gives me `Cannot call setValue on an empty DOMWrapper.` error.

> Test file

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Create from './Create.vue';
// import State from '@/components/State.vue';

describe('it tests Create component', () => {
    test('it emits create event and resets the form when form is valid and create button is clicked', async () => {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = 'root';
        document.body.append(div);

        const expectedNameValue = 'TODO_NAME';
        const expectedStateValue = 'Pending';

        const wrapper = mount(Create, {
            attachTo: '#root',
        });

        await wrapper.find(`input`).setValue(expectedNameValue);
        await wrapper.findComponent({ ref: 'state-component' }).find('select').setValue(expectedStateValue);        
        
        await wrapper.find(`form`).trigger('submit');

        expect(wrapper.emitted().create).toBeTruthy();
        expect(wrapper.emitted().create[0]).toEqual([expectedNameValue]);
        expect(wrapper.emitted().create[1]).toEqual(['Pending']);
        expect(wrapper.find(`input[name='name']`).element.value).toEqual('');
        expect(wrapper.find(`input[name='state']`).element.value).toEqual('Pending');
    });
});
```

> `Create` component

```html
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="createTodo" class="flex gap-2 w-full">
        <input class="flex-1 shadow rounded-md p-2 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-900 focus:outline-none" type="text" placeholder="Todo Name" name="name" required/>
        <State ref="state-component"/>
        <button type="submit" class="rounded-md shadow text-white bg-blue-700 py-2 px-6">Create</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
import State from '@/components/State.vue';

export default {
    components: { State },
    emits: ['create'],
    methods: {
        createTodo(event) {
            const elems = event.target.elements;
            const todo = { name: elems.name.value, state: elems.state.value };
            this.$emit('create', todo);

            elems.name.value = '';
            elems.state.value = 'Pending';
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

> `State` component

```html
<template>
  <select id="state-select" class="rounded-md bg-green-200 text-white" name="state">
    <option
      v-for="(state, index) in states"
      :selected="isSelected(state)"
      :key="index"
    >
      {{ state }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["todo", "index"],
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      state: "",
      states: ["Pending", "In Progress", "Done"],
    };
  },
  created() {
    if(!this.todo) return true;

    this.state = this.todo.state;
    this.name = this.todo.name;
  },
  methods: {
    isSelected(equivalent){
      return equivalent === this.state;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

I'm fairly new to VueJS so I'm open to all tips and tricks, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some issues to fix:

1. You don't need to attach the component to the document, so remove that:

   ```js
   // ❌
   // const div = document.createElement('div');
   // div.id = 'root';
   // document.body.append(div);
   // const wrapper = mount(Create, { attachTo: '#root' });

   // ✅
   const wrapper = mount(Create);
   ```
2. The template ref to the `State` component would be the component's root element, so no need to `find()` the `<select>`:

   ```js
   // ❌
   // await wrapper.findComponent({ ref: 'state-component' }).find('select').setValue(expectedStateValue);
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   // ✅
   await wrapper.findComponent({ ref: 'state-component' }).setValue(expectedStateValue);
   ```
3. The `emitted()` object key is the event name, and the value is an array of of arrays, containing emitted data. You can verify the first `create`-event data contains another object with [`toMatchObject(object)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tomatchobjectobject):

   ```js
   // ❌
   // expect(wrapper.emitted().create[0]).toEqual([expectedNameValue]);
   // expect(wrapper.emitted().create[1]).toEqual(['Pending']);

   // ✅
   expect(wrapper.emitted().create[0][0]).toMatchObject({ name: expectedNameValue, state: 'Pending' });
   ```
4. The last assertion tries to find `input[name='state']`, but that's actually a `<select>`, not an `<input>`:

   ```js
   // ❌
   // expect(wrapper.find(`input[name='state']`).element.value).toEqual('Pending')
                           ^^^^^
   // ✅
   expect(wrapper.find(`select[name='state']`).element.value).toEqual('Pending')
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-test-vue-compnents?file=tests%2Funit%2FCreate.spec.js)